# Concat Arrays cells in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matrix, concatenation

I have 3 single-cell arrays (no text, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

```
A1 = {"A","B","C"}

B1 = {"1","2","3"}

C1 = {"X","Y","Z"}
```

I need to concat them

```
D1 = "A 1 X , B 2 Y , C 3 Z"
```

The formula should works for bigger arrays, no just 3 elements.
I can't use VB.

Thanks you can take a look to https://www.freelancer.com/contest/Excel-Formula-1660332

Comment: I forgot, without VB

Comment: You'll need a function called TEXTJOIN. You have access depending on your excel license

Comment: You are going to have a long formula on hand if TEXTJOIN is not available. Also will it always be 3 cells and 3 values in each cell case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `TEXTJOIN` function on my home computer. So when I tried with following constraints

- There will be three cells.
- Each cell will have 3 entries with above constant structure.

Then following very long formula can be used.

`=""""&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),99,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),99,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&C1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),99,99))," , ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),198,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),198,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&C1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),198,99))," , ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),297,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),297,99)),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&C1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),297,99))),""""," "))&"""`

At its core following extracting logic has been used repetitively.

`TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),"{",""),"}",""),99,99))`

**My suggestion:** Use VBA if you don't have `TEXTJOIN` option.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and answer, I wasn't clear enough, I edit the question now to be accurate, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that: `{"A1X","B2Y","C3Z"}={"A","B","C"} & {"1","2","3"} & {"X","Y","Z"}`

There are all sorts of ways to combine and deliminate text but in sticking with the knowing how to use arrays in functions theme we can answer this question in a single function like this:

```
=LET(myText,TEXTJOIN(",",,{"A","B","C"} & {"1","2","3"} & {"X","Y","Z"}),
TEXTJOIN(" ",,MID(myText,SEQUENCE(LEN(myText)),1)))
```

Just replace the input arrays with references to your large arrays.

This excel syntax for implicit joins is useful to know as it simplifies so many functions.

`{"AY","AZ"}="A"&{"Y","Z"}`
`{"AY","BZ"}={"A","B"}&{"Y","Z"}`